# are ".o" files "loadable"?

Tags: object, linker, loader, elf

I have been reading John R. Levine's Linkers and Loaders and I read that the properties of an object file will include one or more of the following.

1. file should be linkable
2. file should be loadable
3. file should be executable

Now, considering this example:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
  printf("testing\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Which I would compile and link with:

```
$ gcc -c t.c
$ gcc -o t t.o
```

I tried inspecting `t.o` using `objdump` and its type shows up as `REL`. What all properties does `t.o` satisfy? I believe that its linkable, non-executable. I would have believed that its not loadable(unless you create an .so file from the .o file); however the type `REL` means that its supposed to be relocated, and relocation would occur only in the context of loading, so I'm having a confusion here.
My doubts summarized :-

1. Are ".o" files `loadable`?
2. Reading resources regarding the sections present in a ".o", ".so" file - differences etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object file (i.e., a file with the .o extension) is not loadable. This is because it lacks critical information about how to resolve all the symbols within it: in this case, the `println` symbol in particular would need additional information. (C compilers do not bind library identities into the object files they create, which is occasionally even useful.)

When you link the object file into a shared library (.so), you are adding that binding. Typically, you're also grouping a number of object files together and resolving references between them (plus a few more esoteric things). That then makes the result possible to load, since the loader can then just do resolution of references and loading of dependencies that it doesn't already know about.

Going from there to executable is typically just a matter of adding on the OS-defined program bootstrap. This is a small piece of code that the OS will start the program running by calling, and it typically works by loading the rest of the program and dependencies and then calling `main()` with information about the arguments. (It's also responsible for exiting cleanly if main returns.)

Comment: by program bootstrap, are you referring to libc_start_main ?

Comment: @eQuiNoX__ I'm referring to the code that's usually located (before linking) in a file that's referred to as `crt0.o`, though modern linkers might actually hold the code internally.

Answer (score 1):

Just to set the context [this link](http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker03.html) states somethings similar (emphasis for readability only);

> A file may be **linkable**, used as input by a link editor or linking
>   loader. It my be **executable**, capable of being loaded into
>   memory and run as a program, **loadable**, capable of being loaded
>   into memory as a library along with a program, or any combination of
>   the three.

A .o file is a linker object file, which is according to this definition **not executable** and **definitely linkable**. Loadable is a tougher call, but since .o files are not loadable without some definitely not cross platform trickery, I'd say the spirit is that it's **not loadable**.